# xtrabackup: File '/var/lib/mysql/binlog.000010' not found (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)

Tags: mysql, backup

I’m first time using percona Xtrabackups. And, while taking full backup with it, I see this error message at the end of log:
Below command I used to take backup:

```
 xtrabackup --backup --host=xx.xxx.xx.x --user=root --password=xxxx --target-dir=/home/taramaakijay049/backup --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
```

Detailed log:

https://ctxt.io/2/AABw5ztaEQ

That’s true that there’s no binlog.000010 at the moment. But, I’m not sure why is it looking for it and then throwing this error message. But, there are binlog1 to 9 files when I check the backup taken by xtrabackup in my backup folder, I don’t even see 1 to 9 files as well.
Not sure, why it didn’t copy of rest my binlog files. Any suggestion  to fix this behavior will be greatly appreciated.

Also, here's the output of `show binary logs` from source db:

```
mysql> show binary logs;
+---------------+-----------+-----------+
| Log_name      | File_size | Encrypted |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+
| binlog.000001 |       180 | No        |
| binlog.000002 |       404 | No        |
| binlog.000003 |       157 | No        |
| binlog.000004 |       180 | No        |
| binlog.000005 |       748 | No        |
| binlog.000006 |       392 | No        |
| binlog.000007 |       201 | No        |
| binlog.000008 |       201 | No        |
| binlog.000009 |       157 | No        |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

[image]

Additional info

```
 mysql> SELECT * FROM performance_schema.log_status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
    SERVER_UUID: 828049d5-c3f3-11ee-88bc-42010ab60004
          LOCAL: {"gtid_executed": "", "binary_log_file": "binlog.000006", "binary_log_position": 157}
    REPLICATION: {"channels": []}
STORAGE_ENGINES: {"InnoDB": {"LSN": 20509927, "LSN_checkpoint": 20509927}}
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: It might help if you add the full `xtrabackup` command you used and provide the full xtrabackup log (masking sensitive information). Also include the output of `SHOW BINARY LOGS` from the source server.

Comment: Thank you @jerichorivera , I have added requested details in the question

Comment: Can you share output of `SELECT * FROM performance_schema.log_status\G`? I suspect there's something in the `LOCAL` column that instructs PXB to include the non-existent binary log file.

Comment: @jerichorivera - added

Comment: might be a bug of some sort. I would suggest creating a bug report in Percona's bug tracking system.